# Dihedral extensions and the Ankeny - Artin - Chowla conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

Jensen and Yui (Polynomials with D<sub>p</sub> as Galois group
J. Number Theory 15, 347-375 (1982)) proved that if p = 4n+1
is a regular prime, then there is no normal extension of the
rationals with Galois group D<sub>p</sub> (dihedral of order 2p)
ramified only at p. When I first read it I noticed that such an
extension exists if and only if p divides u, where $t+u\sqrt{p}$
is the fundamental unit of the real quadratic number field with
discriminant p (Ankeny, Artin and Chowla conjectured that this
never happens; it is known that this property is equivalent to
the divisibility of the Bernoulli number B<sub>(p-1)/2</sub> by p,
hence implies that p is irregular).

I recall having seen this result in print a few years later, 
but can't find it anymore. Can anyone help me?

Comment: reference-request tag?

Comment: Maybe the result is in Louboutin, Park, and Lefeuvre, Construction of the real dihedral number fields of degree $2p$, Acta Arith 89 (1999) 201-215, MR 2000g:11101. 

Comment: Another paper that might be relevant is Bernat Plans, On the minimal number of ramified primes in some solvable extensions of {\bf Q}, Pac J Math 215 (2004) 381-391. 

Answer (score 2):

As I am currently writing up my [thesis](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Eflemmermeyer/thesis.html) in English I noticed that I had referred to this result in the preface. It appears as Proposition 1 in an article by [Nakagoshi](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/nagoya-mathematical-journal/volume-115/issue-none/On-the-unramified-extensions-of-the-prime-cyclotomic-number-field/nmj/1118781356.full). See also the recent article by [Cohen and Thorne](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.09153.pdf).